# Unlock AD account based on partial name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im looking to quickly unlock AD accounts.   I want to enter in the partial name e.g. donald d

have it return e.g.

donald duck            locked

donald donovan   disabled

donald davids        enabled

Then choose e.g.  donald duck to be unlocked

So I need to list the relevant accounts including locked accounts and quickly select the locked one.

So far I have below.   It doesn't display locked accounts and I cant act upon the output.

```
$name = read-host 'Whats the name'

Get-Aduser -Filter "name -like '$name*'" | select name,enabled  | Format-List
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two possible solutions you could try. I don't have AD available at the moment so it is untested.

## GUI

```psh
$name = Read-Host 'Whats the name'

Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$name*'" | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Enabled | #Get users
Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select the user you want to unlock" | #Create menu
ForEach-Object {
    #Unlock selected user
    "Unlocking $($_.Name)"
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $_.SamAccountName
}
```

## CLI

```psh
$users = @(Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$name*'")
if($users.Count -gt 0) {
    #Create menu
    Write-Host "Matching users:"
    Write-Host "---------------"

    $i = 1
    $users | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host ("{0}. {1} - {2} - {3}" -f $i, $_.Name, $_.SamAccountName, $_.Enabled)
        $i++
    }

    #Select a user
    $selecteduser = Read-Host "Please select the user you would like to unlock (1-$($users.Count))"
    while ($selecteduser -lt 1 -or $selecteduser -gt $users.Count) {
        Write-Host "Invalid user selected, try again." -ForegroundColor Red
        $selecteduser = Read-Host "Please select the user you would like to unlock (1-$($users.Count))"
    }

    #Unlock selected user
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity ($users[$selecteduser-1])

} else {
    Write-Host "No matching users found"
}
```

Comment: Ive tried the CLI version.  Thats very good,  id like to show the locked out status as well as the enabled/diabled status.  I have tried to add $_.Lockedout  at the end of the write-host but it didnt work.    Ive tested and this can be displayed e.g.  Get-Aduser -Filter "name -like '$name*'" -properties name,enabled,samaccountname,PasswordExpired,lockedout.    -Thanks

Comment: Great that you figured it out. Modify the `Write-Host` in your loop to include the properties you want, ex. `Write-Host ("{0}. {1} - {2} - Enabled: {3} - LockedOut: {4}" -f $i, $_.Name, $_.SamAccountName, $_.Enabled, $_.LockedOut)`

Comment: Nearly there.  The $_.lockedOut  part never return's true or false in the output.  yet $_.enabled does return true or false.

Comment: Did you also replace the `Get-ADUser` with the one in your comment? It's not a standard property, so you have to define it with `-Properties LockdOut`.

Comment: Of course. That works.  I have put that into the CLI version get-aduser...  Im trying to format the output to be cleaner with an equal spacing between the output presently its as below.  
---------------
1. Princess Diana - dianap - Enabled: True - LockedOut: False
2. princess leia - leia - Enabled: True - LockedOut: False
3. Princess Peppa - peppap - Enabled: True - LockedOut: True    I have researched and see that   't    (escape character t)  is suppose to create a tab between characters  but it dosent in this case

Comment: Its all working great now.  I was simply using the wrong character.   't   instead  of  `t   to Create a Tab between the output.    That was a really helpful and comprehensive answer and Ill be studying how it all works.    Many Thanks   -Confuseis

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick way to unlock locked accounts matching a partial name, I'd do something like this:

```psh
function Invoke-SimpleUnlock {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter()][string]$Name = ''
  )

  Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$Name*'" -Property LockedOut |
    ? { $_.LockedOut } |
    Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm
}
```

The above will fetch all locked out AD accounts beginning with the string provided via the parameter `-Name` (all if the parameter was omitted), and then prompt you to unlock them (`-Confirm`).

If you want a list of matching users and their status before proceeding to unlocking accounts you could modify the function like this:

```psh
function Invoke-SimpleUnlock {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter()][string]$Name = ''
  )

  $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$Name*'" -Property LockedOut

  $users | select Name, @{n='Status';e={
    if (-not $_.Enabled) {
      'Disabled'
    } elseif ($_.LockedOut) {
      'Locked'
    } else {
      'Enabled'
    }
  }} | sort Name | Format-Table -AutoSize

  $users | ? { $_.LockedOut } | Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm
}
```